# how to give equal width to all tabs?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

[image]
hello 
could you please tell me why on landscape it is not acquiring equal width  as in portrait mode ?? is there any way to provide equal width into tabs in portrait mode.

I do like this

**landscape** 
**potrait**

[image]

here is my code ..in portrait it is taking equal width but on landscape it is not taking the equal width why ?

here is my code

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
   ActionBar actionBar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PageAdapter pageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pageAdapter =new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
         actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(this));

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i){

            case 0:
                return new Fragmentone();
            case 1:
                return  new Fragmenttwo();
            case 2:
                return  new FragmentThree();
            default:
                break;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: actionbar will wrap the tab size according to the content in it. better place your view in some other container view and set them to equal size

Comment: COULS YOU GIVE SOME CODE

Comment: here is a good tutorial take a look http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html